# Integrating exponential pdf for mgf

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, moment-generating-functions

I would like to integrate the following function but unfortunately I am  not getting to the right outcome

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{tx}\frac 16\left(e ^{-\frac x2}+xe^{-\frac x2}\right)$$

Comment: what do we know about $t$?

Comment: What have you already tried to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $h(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{tx}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\mathrm{d}x$, then
$$
h(t)
=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x\left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right)}\mathrm{d}x
=\frac{2}{1-2t}
$$
Now observe that
$\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{tx}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\mathrm{d}x=h'(t)=\frac{4}{(1-2t)^{2}}$

and so the integral you seek equals $\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{1-2t}+\frac{2}{(1-2t)^{2}}\right)$